# Give different id's to menu section and footer section

Tags: html

HTML

Home

News

Photos

Videos

Schedule

Links

Comment: hi, which issue that your facing?

Comment: I am issue in CSS. I put background and did coding but I can't see any background image on screen. Also, I did css coding for menu section, but it is effecting footer section too. I think because of li tags.

Comment: please keep diffrent class for ul and div. because it will apply to both ul and div of menu. May be that's your facing some issue.

Comment: ohhh..check url of image by inspecting.

Comment: sagar. i dont know how to use different tags in css. I did for html but don't know how to do that for css.

Comment: is there a live example you can show us?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="HeaderMenu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>


<ul id="footerMenu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And address them separately in CSS as this :

```
    body{
    background: #cccccc url("http://www.paradise.lk/images/pattern.png") no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
p.text{
    text-align: center;
}


#HeaderMenu li {
    float: left;
}

#HeaderMenu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#HeaderMenu li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: red;
    color:black;
}


#footerMenu li {
   float: left;
}

#footerMenu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footerMenu li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #2d6a05;
    color:black;
}

ul.HeaderMenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: -1px;

    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #156611;
}
ul.footerMenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: -1px;

    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #156611;
}



#logo img {
    height: 90px;
    width: 212px;


}
.box {
    background-color: #4b4244;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
}
.box1 {
    background-color:white;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

Now do your styles separately for header and footer menus.

Comment: I tried your solution for tags but It's not working again. Can you edit

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    background: #cccccc url("http://hdnaturewall.com/wallpaper/2015/10/sky-blue-wallpaper-background-18-desktop-background.jpg") no-repeat 0px -501px;
}
```